# Error: msvcp90.dll is missing on running an application built in visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

I have a project which I am trying to run (in both normal and debug modes) but every time I run it, it throws the error:

`The program cannot start because MSVCP90.dll missing from your computer. Try re installing to fix your problem`.

After going through lot of posts about the same problem I've tried the following things but nothing seems to work.

1. Found this .dll file in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Synchronization Service\Bin\Microsoft.VC90.CRT` and copy pasted it in `C:\Windows\System32\`. Checked that the environmental variable `path` has system32 in it.
2. Checked in the project properties and have set the `Embed Manifest` option under `Manifest Tool-> Input and Output` as `Yes` for Debug as well as Release modes

The project I am building depends on 3 other projects (they are in same solution) and have set Embed Manifest as yes for all of them. Another `.exe` built for same project built on other machine runs perfectly fine on my machine but the one that I build on the same machine does not work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to install the "official" Microsoft Redistributable on all target PCs that will run your app:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11895

Comment: But what I assume is that since one instance of the app (built on some other machine) runs fine on this machine, the required things are already in place.

Comment: Not always - the executable looks at the registry to find the runtime DLLs.  The way to avoid this is to 1) build as multithreaded (/MT) - not multithreaded DLL (/MD) or 2) add the runtime DLLs to the same directory as your executable or 3) install the official redist as FoggyDay recommended.

Comment: @cup I copy pasted the dlls in the project directory and now I have this error: "The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b)".Any idea why could that be?

Comment: The first hit on Google: http://www.bitdefender.com/support/how-to-solve-error-message-"the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-%280x000007b%29-click-ok-to-close-the-application"-1106.html: "This error message may occur on 64 bit operating systems when the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package is not properly configured".